# Abstracting a class with inheritance

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I'm still trying to wrap my head around class inheritance in Python so bear with me: if I have two very similar classes:

```
class Red:
    def print_color(self):
        print('red')

class Blue:
    def print_color(self):
        print('blue')
```

What's the proper way to inherit these classes to create an abstract class (let's say `Color`) that gets initialized with some sort of an argument that determines which underlying class gets used? After initializing, I should be able to do this:

```
>>> a = Color('red')
>>> a.print_color()
red
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be inheritance at all.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sorry, if you suggest better wording, I can edit the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make that desired example work exactly as is, this is all you need:

```
class Color:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color

    def print_color(self):
        print(self.color)
```

No inheritance, nothing.

If you actually want `Color('red')` to result in an *instance* of the class `Red`, then `Color` just needs to be a factory function:

```
def Color(color):
    constructors = {'red': Red, 'blue': Blue}
    return constructors[color]()
```

Still no inheritance involved here.

Answer (score 1):

So there are a lot of possible answers, but I think a very good one is called the Factory Design Pattern.  It's covered in a lot of different places, but here is one that looks decent.

http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Factory.html

Comment: Ha, perfect! That's exactly what I was looking for. And thanks for the great resources!

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers by putting relevant information directly in your answer. The link is fine as a further resource.

Comment: @mart1n thank you, I would appreciate an upvote or an acceptance of my answer if it helped you.  Thanks.

Comment: @chepner could you please point me to some documentation from stack overflow that shows my answer is not in the spirit?  I gave him an exact answer, he wants to use the Factor Design Pattern.  Then I provided a link to something that explains the Factory Design Pattern.  What exactly do you want me to do?  copy and paste from their website here?  Paraphrase something that is already quite clearly explained somewhere else?  I didn't just put a link down with no explanation or anything.

Comment: The OP could not solve his problem without following the link. Knowing that the Factory Design Pattern exists is not enough to know *how* to apply it.

Comment: @chepner right, but is the point of this site to teach entire topics or answer questions.  It seems pretty obvious to me that the issue wasn't his ability to apply the design pattern, it was ignorance of his existence.  Why would I take away an opportunity for him to learn on his own how to apply it?  If he has issues applying it he can always come back and ask another question or leave a comment.  His question was "What's the proper way" and the answer is "The Factory Design Pattern".  Do we always have to do their work for them to have it be considered a "good answer"??

Comment: From the link, in case you didn't bother reading it: "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline." If you have a problem with that, take it to meta.stackoverflow.com. This is not the appropriate place to discuss it.